Can someone explain what these router options mean? Source MAC address and destination MAC address
Can someone explain what these router options mean? Source MAC address and destination MAC address:


They are the MAC addresses of the network interfaces that are incoming and outgoing. Eg: traffic from your pc to a router, etc. Without more context as to which settingspage you are in, its hard to give you a better answer that probably tells you a lot more though. For that reason, this is only a comment, not an answer.

MAC Addresses
MAC is short for Media Access Control and in most modern wired networks it refers to an Ethernet address that is typically fixed in the firmware of the computer's Ethernet interface. A wireless network has an equivalent hardware address built into it's WiFi networking interface circuitry.
These MAC addresses are different from Internet Protocol (IP) addresses and work at a lower level. Local communications use MAC addresses. IP addresses are translated into MAC addresses using the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) before being transmitted in network packets. That is why your screenshot mentions that MAC address filters also affect both IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses.
A typical network packet transmitted by a PC will have a source MAC address of the PC sending the packet, a destination MAC address of the device to which the packet is intended to be delivered (the destination) as well as IP addresses that can effect delivery of packets outside your local network.
For packets to be delivered outside your local network, the destination MAC address will be that of the router local to the sending PC, but the IP address will not be that of the local router but that of the eventual intended destination for example a public web-server, or the apparent external address of that because of network address translation (NAT) used by the local network containing the web-server.
You would need to find out the MAC addresses in use by the relevant network interfaces of both computers that you want to allow to talk to each other if you are applying some strict controls in your router.
MAC addresses can be found using system configuration settings tools or from the command line
C:\> ipconfig /all

...
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   ...
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : FF-9C-FF-FC-FF-78

A typical modern PC will have several such hardware addresses. In many case they can also be altered by configuration tools. Therefore be careful when using them.

Filtering
I doubt most people use this feature. You would do so if you want to protect or isolate some groups of devices for security reasons.
You should only use this feature of your router if you are certain you understand its purpose and its modes of usage. Otherwise you will likely cause your network to become inoperative for some or all devices.

In simple way we have two type of address in communications :

in local network( layer two addresses - Mac addresses)
in global network-internet ( layer three addresses - IP addresses
)

in local networks we just use MAC addresses for communications
but in global networks we use IP & MAC (because packets go through local networks too we need MAC addresses too but they change in each local networks)
MAC :

every network interface has unique MAC address (in world)
every network device may have one or more network interface for
example : my laptop has 1 LAN interface -  1 wifi interface so it has
two MAC Addresses

communication:

sender network interface : source MAC address
receiver network interface : destination MAC address

there is different ways base on a device or Operating System to find MAC address.
you can search the internet
